# sending room temp data from multiple esp8266's to Mega 2560 to control CH gas boiler

Tags: arduino-mega

My existing Arduino Mega set up has been in use for about 4 years controlling my gas CH system & heat pump HW system using an Arduino mega & 13 'wired' DS18B20 sensors; 2 of these sensors monitor the main room (lounge) temperature & 1 sensor monitors the outside temp. These 3 sensors control the CH by gas boiler using an algorithm that constantly adjusts the room temp setting as the outside temp changes. The others monitor HW tank temps, heat pump inlet & outlet temps.

I want to change this 'single zone' CH control to a 'multi zone' control using many more temp sensors (DS18B20 or ESP8266?) but laying in hidden wiring would be a real pain.

I've been looking at using ESP8266-07 as a wireless temp sensor for each 'zone', sending its data to the Mega for processing by the above refered to algorithm, so that the Mega can control the CH system better but I can't find any reference to receiving this wireless data at the Mega for processing within the IDE sketch.

I've tried testing the nRF24L01 & nRF24L01+ but my house has many 'black' reception areas & transmission is unreliable.
My 2.4GHz wireless LAN has 3 extenders around the house so this would be my prefered wireless solution.

Could a wireless 'master' be used at the Mega to process data coming in from the 'slave' sensors or am I misunderstanding this?

My programming skill is limited to 'basic IDE' & I find 'wireless' a bit of a black art (I'm a retired mechanical engineer!)

Answer (score 1):

I am also in the middle of converting the control of my heating, multi-zone, but using Ciseco / Wirelessthings units as temperature sensors both inside and out. See https://www.wirelessthings.net

Simple serial interface is all you need from the Arduino to run these on a network. The coin cell battery lasts for over 1 year running 1 sample / 10min - the sample rate is configured but obviously the more samples you send the more the battery drains. Range seems to be OK and gets through 3 floors in the house and from the outside. I do use external antenna on the Arduino wireless unit to ensure I get all of the sensor readings.

However sounds like your house is BIG if running 3x WIFI extensions where as a single WIFI base station does me fine.

Comment: I've had a look at wirelessthings.net web site.  I want to monitor (zone) each room in the house that is fitted with wireless EQ3 thermostatic radiator valves (8 so far) so using the wirelessthings temperature sensors would amount to around £100!  Also, I need to sample the sensors every 30s or so as it controls the gas boiler hence my intent to not use battery powered devices but mains powered.  I'm still looking for a way to use the ESP8266 with the Arduino Mega.  My house is not that big but being 'split level' has produced a number of poor reception areas hence he use of wireless extenders